# How to setup dynamic URL such as www.abc.com/photos/august/ in Google App Engine?

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine, url, templating

For example, I have the following files in local folders:

user/website/abc/photos/2012/august.html
user/website/abc/photos/2012/september.html

I want to upload these two html pages to GAE and setup the URL as:
(Let's assume that www.abc.com is the domain that I own.)

http://www.abc.com/photos/august/
http://www.abc.com/photos/september/

How can I do this?

The following is my code currently. I haven't found a way to solve it.

main.py:

```
import webapp2
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import util
import os

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        template_values = {}
        path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'index.html')
        self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))

class August(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.out.write(template.render('august.html',None))        

class September(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.out.write(template.render('september.html',None))

def main():
    application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
        ('/', MainHandler),
                ('august', August),
        ('september', September),
        ])
    util.run_wsgi_app(application)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainHandler)],
                              debug=True)
```

app.yaml

```
application: nienyihotw
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /august
  static_files: august.html
  upload: august.html

- url: /september
  static_files: september.html
  upload: september.html

- url: /rootfolder
  static_dir: rootfolder

- url: /.*
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.1"
```

Comment: What is your problem? I think the current app.yaml should do what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
class PhotosHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, year, month):
        path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'photos', year, '%s.html' % month)
        self.response.out.write(template.render(path, None))

// delete the main
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainHandler), 
                               ('/photos/(.*)/(.*)', PhotosHandler)
                              ],
                              debug=True)

#app.yaml

handlers:
- url: /photos/.*
  script: main.app
```

Comment: Just to add to your answer, the docs for webapp2 routing might be helpful to the op http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/routing.html